# jQuery animate search bar on hover of button

Tags: jquery

I have a search bar in a div outside of the search button that is used to show/hide the search bar on hover. I have the search bar div animating BUT I need help to alter the jQuery so that the search bar stays open when the user moves the mouse off the button and into the box.

I have done a Fiddle to show what I have, thanks for any help.

My HTML:

```
<div id="navBar">
   <div class="searchBTN"><button class="search closed">S</button></div>
</div>
<div id="search">
   <div class="searchHolder"></div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
 $('.searchBTN button').hover(function(){
    $('.searchHolder').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
    height: 80
    }, 'slow');
},
function() {
    $('.searchHolder').animate({
        height: 0
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ry7rvxL/12/

Answer (score 1):

You need `hover` event on `#navBar` ( container div ) , not `searchBTN`

```
$('#navBar').hover(function(){
        $('.searchHolder').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        height: 80
        }, 'slow');
    },
    function() {
        $('.searchHolder').animate({
            height: 0
        }, 'slow');
    });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/8ry7rvxL/14/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can attach events to the button and search field separately.

```
$('.searchBTN button').mouseover(function() {
        $('.searchHolder').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        height: 80
        }, 'slow');
});
$('.searchHolder').mouseout(function() {
        $('.searchHolder').animate({
            height: 0
        }, 'slow');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yjr819uk/